# JQuery bind this and data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have a click listener which binds the object values itself and a data attribute of the element which has been clicked.

Example:

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  $(window).on("click", ".myclass", sayHello).bind(this);
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName + data-url);
};

var person1 = new Person("Alice");
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" data-url="google.com" class="myClass">Test</a>
  <a href="#" data-url="google.com" class="myClass">Test</a>
  <a href="#" data-url="google.com" class="myClass">Test</a>
</div>
```

I don't know how to get the data attribute within the sayHello function. But I need the firstName and the data-url within the sayHello function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how are you linking an individual anchor with a `Person`? or all achors are linked with all `Person`s?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for (Not tested but it will help you):

```
$(a).click(function(){

   data_val = $(this).data('url');//will give you data attribute value of clicked anchor element
   var person1 = new Person("Alice", data_val);
}); 

var Person = function (firstName, val) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.val = val;
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName + this.val);
};
```

Comment: Doesn't seems like. The person object needs to be created outside the click event function. Because the links gets created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `sayHello` method to accept additional params and create a link to `this` of the Person object:

```
var Person = function (firstName) {
  var self = this;
  this.firstName = firstName;
  $(window).on("click", ".myclass", function() {
    self.sayHello(this);
  });
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function(element) {
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName + $(element).data('url'));
};

var person1 = new Person("Alice");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getAttribute` javascript function, try

```
console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName + this.getAttribute('data-url'));
```